# "order.price" field is always equal to 0

Tags: personalization, cdp

Does anybody know why **order.price** field is always equal to 0 *(in guest.orders)*?
Is it a bug or I need to pass some additional data with *CHECKOUT* event?
[image]

And if it is equal to zero, does it means that **order.core_price** field in SQL *(Batch segment Advanced mode)* is also equal to 0?:

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, in commerce, an order doesn't have a "price". Products have a price, orders have totals and subtotals. The field isn't documented in the official API docs either, so likely it's a relic from the past that has been left around for compatibility reasons.